# How to play full animation with one press in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

First,Sorry to ask a silly question like that.I am new in as3. i am making a hero move with key-bored. i have 3 animation. 1 standby mode 2 walk front and 3 walk behind.its working well so far but the problem i face in jumping.player have to hold down the key to jump. i don't want the player hold the key to perform jumping. its ok in walking but not in other action.

so i want to play the full animation with one key press and honestly i don't know which function i have to use or how to do it.

Here is my code

```
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;



kim.gotoAndStop("kim Stand");

var dPressed:Boolean = false;
var aPressed:Boolean = false;
var wPressed:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , keyDownHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , KeyUpHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , gameLoop);


function keyDownHandaler(Devent:KeyboardEvent):void

{
    if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            dPressed = true;
        }
    else if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
        {
            aPressed = true;
        }
    else if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
        {
            wPressed = true;
        }
}


function KeyUpHandaler (Uevent:KeyboardEvent):void 

{
if (Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
    {
        dPressed = false;
        kim.gotoAndStop("kim Stand");
    }
else if(Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
    {
        aPressed = false;
        kim.gotoAndStop("kim Stand");
    }
else if(Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
    {
        wPressed = false;
        kim.gotoAndStop("kim Stand");
    }


}

function gameLoop (Gevent:Event):void

{

if (dPressed)
    {
        kim.x += 5;
        kim.gotoAndStop("kim Move Right");
    }
else if(aPressed)
    {
        kim.x -= 5;
        kim.gotoAndStop("kim Move Left");
    }
else if(wPressed)
    {
        kim.gotoAndStop("kim Jump");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you have a full animation at the frame label "kim Jump" in your kim MovieClip between keyFrame 5 and 10, you could do something like

```
// this will check if the jumping animation is already playing if the user press and holds the jump key and disable steerings
var jumping:Boolean;

function gameLoop (Gevent:Event):void
{

if (dPressed)
{
    kim.x += 5;

    if(!jumping)
        kim.gotoAndStop("kim Move Right");
}
else if(aPressed)
{
    kim.x -= 5;

    if(!jumping)
        kim.gotoAndStop("kim Move Left");
}
else if(wPressed)
{
    if(!jumping)
        kim.gotoAndPlay("kim Jump");

    jumping = true;
}

}
```

And at the last frame of your jumping animation you'd need

```
_parent.jumping = false;
gotoAndStop("Your label for no animation");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but i am total new in as3 and i still don't know many function _parent is one of them. 

so its having a error , its say

Access of undefined property _parent. not finding any solution

Comment: This code should be inside of your kim MovieClip at the last frame of your jumping animation. It's a MovieClip, right ? Then there should be a _parent property which is a reference to the parent movieclip